# Spring Security two roles implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm new to spring security method. I'm trying to implement two user's in my web application. (Admin Role & User Role)
I have two re-directions pages using thymeleaf for admin it should drop to /admin/** and for users it should be /user/**

I've tried adding two spring security class using @order(1) and order(2) but still not working.. my aim is if the user logins and has roles in my security it should redirect to the correct pages.

Please see my code below

```
spring.queries.users-query=select email, password, enabled from user where email=?
spring.queries.roles-query=select u.email, r.role from user u inner join user_role ur on (u.id=ur.user_id) inner join role r on(ur.role_id=r.role_id) where u.email=?

    @Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth.
        jdbcAuthentication()
            .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/confirm").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/forgotpassword").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/criminal/getAllWantedCriminal").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/criminal/viewCriminal").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAuthority("USER")
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/home")
        .usernameParameter("email")
        .passwordParameter("password")
        .and().logout()
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
}
```

Comment: can you post your controller also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is creating a custom [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html)

There, once the user has correctly logged in, you could just check wether the 
[Authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) object has `ROLE_ADMIN` to redirect to default configured success url (the default user success url) or to the admin one. This is a working sample, extending [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler.html):

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

public class RoleBasedAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler
        implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private String adminRoleTargetUrl;

    private String adminRoleAuthority;

    /**
     * @param defaultTargetUrl
     */
    public RoleBasedAuthenticationSuccessHandler(String defaultTargetUrl, String adminRoleTargetUrl, String adminRoleAuthority) {
        super(defaultTargetUrl);
        this.adminRoleTargetUrl = adminRoleTargetUrl;
        this.adminRoleAuthority = adminRoleAuthority;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler#onAuthenticationSuccess(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, org.springframework.security.core.Authentication)
     */
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if(isAdmin(authentication)){
            this.getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, this.getAdminRoleTargetUrl());
            return;
        }
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }

    /**
     * @param authentication
     */
    protected boolean isAdmin(Authentication authentication) {
        for(GrantedAuthority authority : authentication.getAuthorities()){
            if(authority.getAuthority().equals(this.getAdminRoleAuthority())){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @return the adminRoleTargetUrl
     */
    public String getAdminRoleTargetUrl() {
        return adminRoleTargetUrl;
    }

    /**
     * @return the adminRoleAuthority
     */
    public String getAdminRoleAuthority() {
        return adminRoleAuthority;
    }   

}
```

Then, change your security config class in order to set the `RoleBasedAuthenticationSuccessHandler` instance in method `successHandler` instead of using `defaultSuccessUrl` :

```
@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.
        jdbcAuthentication()
        .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/confirm").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/forgotpassword").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/criminal/getAllWantedCriminal").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/criminal/viewCriminal").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAuthority("USER")
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
        .successHandler(this.getSuccessHandler())
        .usernameParameter("email")
        .passwordParameter("password")
        .and().logout()
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
    }

    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler getSuccessHandler() {
        return new RoleBasedAuthenticationSuccessHandler(
                    "/user/home",
                    "/admin/home",
                    "ROLE_ADMIN"                
                );

    }
```

Comment: I will try to implement this.